# PHP Css Array dividing each value with units at the end

Tags: php, css

I am working on what I thought would be a simple task in php. The goal is to take a style sheet and divide all values by 2. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$css = fopen("stylesheet.css", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
preg_match_all( '/(?ims)([a-z0-9\s\,\.\:#_\-@]+)\{([^\}]*)\}/', $css, $arr);

$result = array();
foreach ($arr[0] as $i => $x)
{
    $selector = trim($arr[1][$i]);
    $rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
    $result[$selector] = array();
    foreach ($rules as $strRule)
    {
        if (!empty($strRule))
        {
            $rule = explode(":", $strRule);
            $result[$selector][][trim($rule[0])] = trim($rule[1]);
        }
    }
}   

var_dump($result);
?>
```

My CSS sheet is pretty simple as well

```
.text_1_1 {
  width: 419px;
  height: 101.5px;
  background-size: 1459.5px 632.5px;
  background-position: -486px -255.5px;
}
.text_1_2 {
  width: 393.5px;
  height: 49.5px;
  background-size: 1459.5px 632.5px;
  background-position: -7px -398.5px;
}
```

and my output looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  [".text_1_1"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["width"]=>
      string(5) "419px"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["height"]=>
      string(7) "101.5px"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["background-size"]=>
      string(16) "1459.5px 632.5px"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["background-position"]=>
      string(15) "-486px -255.5px"
    }
  }
  [".text_1_2"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["width"]=>
      string(7) "393.5px"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["height"]=>
      string(6) "49.5px"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["background-size"]=>
      string(16) "1459.5px 632.5px"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["background-position"]=>
      string(13) "-7px -398.5px"
    }
  }
}
```

Now for the part that has me confused, I would like to go into this array and divide all numbers by 2 which I assume I can achieve with a for each, but how do I get it to ignore the "px" at the end of each value?

Thanks for the help, I know it has to be something easy and I am just missing it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php ... which I just realized wouldn't work for values like `"1459.5px 632.5px"` ... `str_replace('px', '', ...)` maybe?

Comment: explode the string by white space, loop trough it and then string str_replace function to remove the px then you can muliply the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Replace the block

```
{
    $rule = explode(":", $strRule);
    $pxless = str_replace("px","", trim($rule[1]));
    $arr = explode(" ", $pxless);
    for($j=0; $j<count($arr); $j++) $arr[$j]=($arr[$j]/2)."px";
    $finally = implode(" ", $arr);
    $result[$selector][][trim($rule[0])] = $finally;
}
```

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but how do I go about converting this array back into a string?

Comment: $str="";
foreach ($result as $selector => $block) {
  $str.=$selector."{";
  foreach($block as $i => $rule) {
    foreach($rule as $attr => $val) {
          $str .= $attr.": ".$val.";";
    }
  }
  $str .="} ";
}
echo $str;

Answer (score 0):

> vice versa

```
$str="";
    foreach ($result as $selector => $block) {
      $str.=$selector."{";
      foreach($block as $i => $rule) {
        foreach($rule as $attr => $val) {
              $str .= $attr.": ".$val.";";
        }
      }
      $str .="} ";
    }
```

Comment: put before var_dump